# Access static members in mixins

Tags: static-methods, mixins, qooxdoo

The instruction `this.constructor` doesn't work in mixins. I get an **undefined** value. I wonder why it happens and is it possible to use this instruction. There is a code example:

```
qx.Mixin.define("MZoomable", {
    statics: {
      MAX_ZOOM: 500
    },
    
    members: {
      printMaxZoom: function(){
        alert(this.constructor.MAX_ZOOM);
      }  
    }
    
});

qx.Class.define("MyClass", {
  extend: qx.core.Object,
  include: [MZoomable],
  
  constuct: function(){
    this.base(arguments);
  }
});

const o = new MyClass();
o.printMaxZoom();
```

**alert** in `printMaxZoom` will show **undefined** word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that `this.constructor` refers to the class of the object at runtime, and that would be `MyClass`.  I would expect that if you modified `printMaxZoom` to be:

```
printMaxZoom: function(){
  alert(this.constructor === MyClass);
}
```

Then you would get an alert that says "true".

This is an inherent characteristic an environment where the type is determined (including the addition of a mixin) at runtime.

If you want to refer to static members of a Mixin, you should use the absolute syntax, eg:

```
printMaxZoom: function(){
  alert(MZoomable.MAX_ZOOM);
}
```

Note that it is *always* good practice to use the absolute path for static variables, and it is often a bug to use `this.constructor` as a shortcut.

For example:

```
qx.Class.define("MyClassOne", {
  extend: qx.core.Object,
  
  construct: function(){
    this.base(arguments);
    alert(this.constructor.MY_VALUE);
  },

  statics: {
    MY_VALUE: 23
  }
});


qx.Class.define("MyClassTwo", {
  extend: MyClassOne
});

// creates an alert that says "23"
var one = new MyClassOne();

// creates an alert that says "undefined"
var one = new MyClassTwo();
```

The issue is the same as the one in your question, in that `this.constructor` is the actual class of the object, and **not** the class (or mixin) where the `this.constructor` statement appears.